# Why does MS-DOS 5.0 EDIT hang on my XT-class machine with a German 102-key keyboard?

Tags: ms-dos, ibm-pc, compatibility

Most times whene I call `EDIT` on my XT-class machine with MS-DOS 5.0 installed on the hard disk, the menus of `EDIT` appear, but the window that should contain the file contents stays blank and the machine stops responding to any input.

The BIOS on the machine is made by PHOENIX, and its version string says 2.27.

Comment: Apparently this was not the asker’s problem, but PC DOS 5.0 QBASIC (and in consequence EDIT as well) may also hang because of a ‘genuine IBM hardware’ check: http://www.os2museum.com/wp/ibm-dos-5-0-qbasic-hangs-on-non-ibm-systems/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Analysis of the problem

The cause is an incompatibility with many pieces in it. It is centered around what the bit 4 of `40:96` in the BIOS data area actually means. This bit is documented to mean that a "101/102 key keyboard" is connected to the computer. This is the case in my XT system. The keyboard I use has a switch (8088/80286) to choose the protocol, and in XT mode, it uses the XT keyboard protocol, but it still sends `E0` prefixes like in AT mode when extended keys (like the separate cursor keys) are pressed.

The BIOS on this computer does not know about 101/102-key keyboards, and also does not use `40:96` at all, so it is zeroed out on boot. The `KEYB` command included with MS-DOS 5.0 overrides the BIOS implementation of the keyboard IRQ handler (`INT 09`) with a variant that *does* handle extended keys. If the MS-DOS 5.0 keyboard driver recognizes `E0` or `E1` scan codes (no matter on what machine), it automatically sets the bit indicating the presence of an "extended keyboard". This makes sense.

On the other hand, the keyboard abstraction layer in `QBASIC` (and `EDIT` on DOS 5 is implemented by running `QBASIC` with a special command line switch) attaches more meaning to that bit. If it sees this bit set, `QBASIC` implies that the keyboard BIOS is AT-like, and thus `INT 16` supports the extended BIOS services `10h`, `11h` and `12h` that IBM introduced in the AT. These services are needed to make best use of the 101/102-key keyboard, as they allow (e.g.) to differentiate between the numpad cursor keys with numlock off and the separate cursor keys.

You likely can see where this is heading: As the DOS keyboard driver replaces only `INT 09`, the hardware IRQ driver is now 101/102-key aware, and the awareness is indicated in the BIOS data area *after the first extended key has been pressed*. The BIOS API at `INT 16` is still the PC-class service that only supports subfunctions 0 to 2. As `QBASIC` now tries to interface to the keyboard using the unsupported subfunctionss 10h and 11h, it reads garbage inputs and seems to not draw the file to the screen while some keys (possibly scrolling keys) are pressed.

## A way to fix the problem

Actually, the QBASIC keyboard abstraction layer has an internal flag to disable AT keyboard BIOS support. It does not seem to be set anywhere in QBASIC though. The configuration flags for the driver are in `QBASIC.EXE` in the data segment, but as `QBASIC` is compressed by Microsoft's linker (`/EXEPACK`), the flag byte can not be patched. What can be patched is the instruction that checks the 101-key flag.

```
26 F6 06 96 04 10       test    es:keybd_flags_3, 10h ; 101 key keyboard?
74 16                   jz      NoATSupport
8B 1D                   mov     bx, [di+KbdState.Environment]
83 7F 18 00             cmp     [bx+KbdEnvironment.InhibitATSupport], 0
75 0E                   jnz     NoATSupport
[...]
NoATSupport:
```

The byte sequence `26 F6 06 96 04 10` has only one hit in `QBASIC.EXE`. Patch the last byte to `00` to make sure the zero flag is always set after this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to fix this problem is to execute a small program called "Keyfix.com" that was supplied, largely un-documented, with some OEM distributions of MSDOS 3.2 and 3.3.
Syntax is:

> keyfix /i

Just typing:

> keyfix

will check the keyboard in use and advise whether keyfix needs to be installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only keyfix I could find in archives using google is a keyfix tool by compaq distributed with a pre-release of MS-DOS 3.1 for their Deskpro series computers. This keyfix utitlity uses 286 opcodes and seems to be intended to fix a different problem Do you have any pointers to the keyfix utility you are talking about? Not necesserily a link to a questionable abondonware site, but maybe you can remember which OEM(s) provided keyfix.